# Type deduction of numeric literal to unsigned type

Tags: c++, literals, conditional-operator, auto

I was trying to compile a simple expresion which boils down to

```
myClass* object = new myClass();
std::vector<someType> SomeContainer;
auto N = (object) ? object->GetN() : 0; //GetN() returns <uint16_t>
assert( SomeContainer.size() == N ); // error, comparing signed to unsigned
```

I get that this happens, since

```
rank(uint16_t)=rank(unsigned short int)<rank(int)=rank(0)
```

such that `uint16_t` is promoted to `int` in the `?:` operator, and `N` also becomes an `int`. Thus, I could solve this issue by either of the following lines

```
auto N = (object) ? object->GetN() : 0u; //promotion of <uint16_t> to <uint>, N is <uint>
auto N = (object) ? object->GetN() : static_cast<uint16_t>(0); //no promotion, N is <uint16_t>
auto N = (object) ? static_cast<size_t>(object->GetN()) : 0; //promotion of <uint16_t> to <size_t>, N is <size_t>
```

So either I use a "too large" type for one of the arguments, or I have to use the static_cast on `0`, which doesn't seem very elegant to me. I do not really understand, why the treatment of the literal `0` is that counterintuitive, it really spoils the usage of `auto` in this case.

Shouldn't you expect `N` to have an unsigned type (or even specifically that of `GetN()`)? Which solution should be preferred, or is there no elegant solution?

---

Notably, making `N` const does not help, as it would in:

```
size_t a=0;
auto N=0;
const auto k_N=0;
assert(a==N); // error, comparing signed to unsigned
assert(a==k_N); // true;
```

So shouldn't

```
const auto N = (object) ? object->GetN() : 0;
```

also result in an unsigned type, since `N` is never negative?

---

**Edit:** Compiler is GCC 7.3.1. Happens only in debug build.

Comment: Your *"making N const does not help, as it would in"* does not make much sense... this code does not gives any kind of error. The rule of C++ specify that when using built-in operators (including the conditional one), both values are promoted to the highest rank of the two, that's the C++ rule. The fact that `0` is a literal or not does not affect that rule.

Comment: _"...why the treatment of the literal 0 is that counterintuitive..."_ `0` is a literal integer; literal integer are signed and `int` (or larger) see - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal  Carving out a special case for `0` would make it less intuitive.

Comment: You can use `0u` to make the literal unsigned.

Comment: If you don't like the `static_cast`, you can also use the "inverted C-style cast" constructor syntax: `std:uint16_t{0}`.

Comment: Note that the comment "error, comparing signed to unsigned" indicates that you are using a compiler that does not conform to the C++ language definition. Some people like turning warnings into errors.

Comment: The simplest solution is to say what you mean: `unsigned N = object ? object->GetN() : 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid any unwanted type conversions both now and in the future, then you could force the ternary conditional operator to behave itself with

```
object ? object->GetN() : static_cast<decltype(object->GetN())>(0)
```

Although long-winded, you are at least not hardcoding the types, and the type of this expression will be the type of `object->GetN()`. (Note that `object->GetN()` is not evaluated in the `decltype` - there is no undefined behaviour here.)

Note that `0` is always an octal literal of type `int`. On a platform with a 16 bit `int`, it would have been promoted to an `unsigned int`; likely (though not guaranteed) to be the same type as `std::uint16_t`.